# $_REQUEST key conflict handling

Tags: php, request

How $_REQUEST handles if there is a conflict b/w a get key and a post key. for example:

```
<form action="ex.php?key=1234" method="post">
<input type="text" name="key" value="abcd"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

what will be the output if i write this in ex.php:

```
echo $_REQUEST["key"];
```

Comment: a $_REQUEST is an array containing values from get post and cookie methods.

Comment: It's better to handle `$_GET` and `$_POST` separately in your case.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes i know, just a matter of curiosity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the configuration. In your `php.ini` you can set the order of the request parameters.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order for more information.

Comment: Great knowledge of crazy obscure settings! +1

Comment: Awesome, didn't knew about that. +1